# How are variables passed through the PAM authentication system

Tags: linux, shell, pam

If application A calls a PAM service "myapp", and the PAM service "myapp" is configured to use the pam module **pam_exec.so** (`auth required pam_exec.so myscript`) to call an external shell script:

**Q:** How are the variables (in particular username/password) passed from:

**Application A --> PAM Service "myapp" --> pam_exec.so --> myscript**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer, so it appears, is that it depends on the module being used.

`pam_exec.so` writes a number of variables (as per the man page) to the environment of the shell script, excluding the password. If the password is wanted then you should include the argument expose_authtok and it will then be written to STDIN followed by and  marker.